# Problems creating a JAR file with external classes

Tags: java, linux

```
> java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode, sharing)

> javac -version
javac 17.0.9
```

Hi Community,
I have a problem with creating a jar file and need your help. I am working in a Git and have the following folder structure.

```bash
/mnt/c/git_black/JavaCrypt [git::main *] [Yoga] [18:49]
> tree
.
├── javacrypt
│   ├── manifest.txt
│   ├── MyCryptMain.java
│   ├── RunCopy.java
│   ├── RunDecrypt.java
│   ├── RunEncrypt.java
│   ├── RunGenKeys.java
│   ├── RunnableBase.java
│   ├── RunnableFactory.java
│   ├── RunnableInterface.java
│   └── RunnableKeyValueFactory.java
├── java.sh
├── LICENSE
├── makefile.cmd
├── makefile.sh
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF

4 directories, 18 files
```

The corresponding `manifest.txt` file in the `javacrypt` subfolder looks like this. The `JavaCrypt` folder itself is the root folder of the Git project.

```bash
/mnt/c/git_black/JavaCrypt [git::main *] [Yoga] [18:51]
> cat javacrypt/manifest.txt
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: javacrypt.MyCryptMain
```

```java
// MyCryptMain.java
package javacrypt;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCryptMain {

    private static final String PROG_NAME = "JavaCrypt";

    private static final List<String[]> MY_ARRAY = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"-genkeys", "javacrypt.RunGenKeys"},
        new String[]{"-encrypt", "javacrypt.RunEncrypt"},
        new String[]{"-decrypt", "javacrypt.RunDecrypt"},
        new String[]{"-copy", "javacrypt.RunCopy"}
    );

    private static void usage() {
        String[] msg = {
            "Program '" + PROG_NAME + "'",
            "Usage:",
            "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY.get(0)[0] + " [priv_keyfile] [pub_keyfile]",
            "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY.get(1)[0] + " [pub_keyfile] [ifile] [ofile] ",
            "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY.get(2)[0] + " [privkeyfile] [ifile] [ofile] ",
            "\t" + PROG_NAME + " " + MY_ARRAY.get(3)[0] + " [dummyword] [ifile]  [ofile] ",
            ""
        };

        Arrays.stream(msg).forEach(System.err::println);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RunnableKeyValueFactory runnableKeyValueFactory = new RunnableKeyValueFactory(MY_ARRAY.toArray(new String[0][]));
        int argSize = args.length;

        if (argSize == 0) {
            usage();
        }

        String cmdKey = args[0];

        if (!runnableKeyValueFactory.containsKey(cmdKey)) {
            usage();
        }

        List<String> optArgList = Arrays.asList(args).subList(1, args.length);
        RunnableInterface myRun = runnableKeyValueFactory.getInstanceFromKey(cmdKey);
        myRun.run(optArgList);

        System.out.println("End of the program.");
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert the Java files into a jar. To do this, I first create the `*.class` files.   Then I try to create the jar file.

```bash
cd /mnt/c/git_black
javac -Xlint:unchecked ./javacrypt/MyCryptMain.java
jar cfm JavaCrypt.jar ./javacrypt/makefile.txt javacrypt/*.class
chmod +x JavaCrypt.jar
```

I have a JAR file. But it does not work. Let me show you what I mean.

Under Linux I get the following error message:

```bash
/mnt/c/git_black/JavaCrypt [git::main *] [liffecs@Yoga] [19:33]
> java -jar JavaCrypt.jar
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class javacrypt.MyCryptMain
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javacrypt/MyCryptMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 64.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

Under Windows I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\git_black\JavaCrypt> java -jar .\JavaCrypt.jar
Program 'MyCryptMain'
Usage:
        MyCryptMain -genkeys [priv_keyfile] [pub_keyfile]
        MyCryptMain -encrypt [pub_keyfile] [ifile] [ofile]
        MyCryptMain -decrypt [privkeyfile] [ifile] [ofile]
        MyCryptMain -copy [dummyword] [ifile]  [ofile]

PS C:\git_black\JavaCrypt> java -jar .\JavaCrypt.jar -genkeys
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javacrypt.RunGenKeys
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
        at javacrypt.RunnableFactory.getInstance(RunnableFactory.java:46)
        at javacrypt.RunnableKeyValueFactory.getInstanceFromKey(RunnableKeyValueFactory.java:87)
        at javacrypt.MyCryptMain.main(MyCryptMain.java:89)
PS C:\git_black\JavaCrypt>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You are trying to use the JAR with an older version of Java than the one you built it with (more specifically: older than the one you compiled with).  The easiest way to go would be to compile (and test!) with the oldest version of Java you want to support.  Then expect that users will need that version of Java or newer to use the result.

Comment: Note also that although you may be able to shortcut by specifying a suitable the `-target` option when you compile with your current compiler, as the answers to the dupe target suggest, that's not a sure thing.  The compiler has a limited range of backwards compatibility, and you need to worry not only about classfile version, but also about the features of the associated Java standard library.  It is possible to build your classes to an older classfile version, but still not be able to run them on the associated JVM version.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger  Please excuse my unknowledge in this matter. I installed Java with "sudo apt install default-jre default-jdk" and compiled it as described above. I actually hope that I am using the latest versions of Java and Javac. Unfortunately, I still can't figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: You are running the program on a different Java installation than you compiled it on.  I am pretty sure of this, because the prompt style shows that the compiler is a Linux version installed (I guess) in WSL, whereas the JVM is a Windows version.  Run `java -version` on the Windows side to see what version you have there.  Different Java installations is not inherently a problem (it happens everywhere), but it does open you up to the kind of Java version issue you are experiencing.

Comment: It's not even about using the Linux version on Windows. It would be enough for me to use the Linux version on Linux.

    Windows: 
    java --version
    java 20.0.1 2023-04-18
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
    
    javac --version
    javac 20.0.1

    Debian: 

    > java --version
    openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Debian-1deb12u1)
  
    > javac --version
    javac 17.0.9

Comment: So on Linux, you are using a Java 20 compiler and a Java 17 JVM.  This produces the version mismatch I already described.  This issue is already well covered at the dupe target.  The Windows-side issue appears simpler: the class file for `javacrypt.RunGenKeys` evidently is not in the jar.  That should be easy to confirm, and it probably results from not compiling the corresponding source in the first place.